# prestashop in order confirmation I want get all products but I only get one

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty3

In prestashops product confirmation page I want  to get all the product of the order, but it only displays one (the first product).

I use this code:

```
$products = $order->getProducts();
```

But when I use it in the tpl file I only get one product even though there are multiple 
here is the smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$products item=product}
{$product.product_name}
{$product.product_quantity}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

When order is confirmed then you should use following code.

```
        $new_cart_id = $params['objOrder']->id_cart;
        $this->context->cart = new Cart($new_cart_id);
        $cart_products = $this->context->cart->getProducts();
```

In that first you have to find id_cart. You can get it by cookie also like

```
$this->context->cookie->id_cart;
```

Now you have to make object of that cart by writing code like:

```
        $new_cart_id = $params['objOrder']->id_cart;
        $this->context->cart = new Cart($new_cart_id);
```

When you make the cart object then you can get all products which are ordered by writing code like:

```
$cart_products = $this->context->cart->getProducts();
```

I hope this would help you.